# What does "this" do when used in function brackets?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple page with three buttons. I wanted to make one function that changes the background color of my page on a click. So i somehow made it work.

I am basically wondering what exactly "this" does when i use it in my changecolor brackets?

I kind of have a feeling what it does but i need more objective knowledge.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Panel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>THIS IS SOME TEXT</h1>
        <h2>This is some more text</h2>
        <button class="buttons" id="button1" onclick="changecolor(this)">;P</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="button2" onclick="changecolor(this)">;]</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="button3" onclick="changecolor(this)">;)</button>
    </body>     
</html>
```

My css:

```
    h1{
        background-color: blue;
        float: left;
    }

    h2{
        color: blue;
        float:  left;
        width:100%;

    }

    .buttons{
        float:left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;

    }

#button1{
    background-color:green;
}

#button2{
    background-color:darkgray;
}

#button3{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

My javascript:

```
function changecolor(clickedButton){

    if(clickedButton.id == "button1"){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightgreen";

    }

    if(clickedButton.id =="button2"){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="gray";
    }

    if(clickedButton.id =="button3"){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: fyi: `[` = bracket, `(` = parentheses, `{` = curly brace

Comment: There _must_ be a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Zeta ... I see what you did there :-)

Comment: @Phlume: That pun wasn't even(t) intended.

Comment: @Zeta and Phlume I don't get it

Comment: @AndrewLyndem: Phlume thought that my comment was a bad pun, since you can read it as "*there must be a duplicate of `this` question*".

Comment: Oh lol The word "must" was written in italics so I was trying to figure out that word instead lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In JavaScript `this` always refers to the “owner” of the function we're
>   executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.
>   When we define our faithful function doSomething() in a page, its
>   owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of
>   JavaScript. An onclick property, though, is owned by the HTML element
>   it belongs to.

Via- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 2):

`this` references the [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) the [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) occurred on.

In this case, inside  `changecolor()`, `clickedButton` will reference the `<button>` object that was *clicked*.

Answer (score 1):

It sends a reference of the clicked element to the javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the button element itself.

Answer (score 1):

this is changing your background color for the body of the document. "this" as in this button or object